# How to connect to mysql using eclipse running apache

Tags: java, mysql, database, apache, tomcat

I am creating a dynamic web project in eclipse.  I have my local apache server running and configured with appropriate resource, mysql running and configured with the appropriate port.

I downloaded the appropriate driver, included it in the lib directory - I even tried adding it as an external JAR file to no avail.  On the dynamic web page the result is "error connecting to database".

I created a JSP with the following code:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%><%@ page import="java.io.*"%><%@ page import="com.mysql.*"%><?xml version="1.0"?>

<tours>
<%
 Connection connection = null;
 Statement statement = null;
 ResultSet result = null;

 try {
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
     connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jbdc:mysql://localhost:3306/tours", "root", "root");
     out.println("connected to database!");
 }
 catch(SQLException e) {
     out.print("error connecting to database");
 }
%>


</tours>
```

Please advise...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `out.print("error connecting to database");` to `out.print(e.getMessage());` and you'll likely discover the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Put print after Class.forName() check, if that statement is not printing then problem is driver if that line is printing then problem is mysql database name problem or credential problem

If problem in drive then download from here :

```
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommysqljdbc515jar.htm
```

Problem is u put jbdc instead of jdbc

Code like this

```
<%
 Connection connection = null;
 Statement statement = null;
 ResultSet result = null;

 try {
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
     out.println("Driver is available !");
   connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tours",
    "root", "root");
     out.println("connected to database!");
 }
 catch(SQLException e) {
     out.print("error connecting to database");
 }
%>
```

Comment: MAMP - MySQL config.:



Host localhost

Port 3306

User root

Password root



Table name is ‘tours’.





Project name and JAR path:

using_drivers/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar

Comment: Driver is available ! error connecting to database

That’s a great start!

I will attempt the new driver download...

Comment: You should put the database name instead of table name "tours"

Comment: tours is the DB name.  The table name is tour.

Comment: did you checked the user name and password?

Comment: I set them to - root root

I’m assuming the problem is somewhere in this line:

connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jbdc:mysql://localhost:3306/tours", "root", "root”);

OR with the JAR File

OR with a configuration.


I triple-checked all options...

Comment: first try to do : login to mysql with root and root, then use tours database. Check whether its able to access

Comment: getConnection("jbdc:mysql://localhost:3306/tours"  getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tours"

Comment: Problem is u put jbdc instead of jdbc

Comment: I still haven't verified that this works cause my eclipse crashed and now I am having issues accessing the jsp file.  When I try to open it, it takes me to Adobe...

Comment: I had to remove eclipse completely, then reinstall it.  I did this and reconfigured everything.  Now I am getting a HTTP Status 404 - "The requested resource is not available."

Comment: I reinstalled Eclipse and now I am getting a HTTP 404 error again when running the application.

Comment: Check your tomcat it may problem

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things to take care of here.
1. Make sure that mysql is listening on port 3306.
2. Cross check the database name.

Lastly get the driver jar file in deployment assembly.

If the problem still persists, please print the stacktrace and post it here.

Comment: Host localhost
Port 3306
User root
Password root

Comment: Please print and post stacktrace.

Comment: Jul 19, 2014 2:21:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/rollinfrancois/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
Jul 19, 2014 2:21:39 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin

Comment: Looks like you are missing some dependencies in your classpath. Make sure you have all the required libraries.

Comment: I had to remove eclipse completely, then reinstall it.  I did this and reconfigured everything.  Now I am getting a HTTP Status 404 - "The requested resource is not available."

Comment: I fixed the 404 issue.  I am still getting the "Error connecting to the database" error.  Which dependencies should I have and where?

Comment: You would need your tomcat libraries and mysql connector mostly to do the work.

Comment: Everything is configured.  Still unable to connect to DB.

Comment: What's the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Please check weather your database is started or not i know it should be in comment but i cannot keep it in comment because i don't have sufficient reputations. please try it if it helps you it is fine.

How to start database is shown below:

Click Windows button+r then enter Services.msc in search bar then select Mysql and click start option

Comment: MAMP - Mac.  DB is running.

Answer (score 0):

Printing the stack trace might help it could be because of authorization issue. If the error is related to authorization issue, you may have to change the server configurations.

Comment: org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/rollinfrancois/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:using_drivers' did not find a matching property.